Package 'libapache2-mod-php8.1' has no installation candidate
I got this error on my upgraded process. I unable to upgrade my php version to 8.x, even though i used both ' add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/apache2' and 'sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php'. I tried to set up php to expose my mautic site on my server

This question is similar to: What does "Package  has no installation candidate" mean?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
